# MySQL compare two tables and show the differences

Tags: php, mysql

I've currently got two tables (main one and revisions) and I'm trying to find an easier way (other than a long php script) to display the differences between the latest two entries. I'm basically having a table and I display the differences for every two rows.

Users

| ID | first_name | last_name | bio | country | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | A few words here. | USA | Active |
| 2 | Jack | Jones | Blablabla | UK | Pending |

Users_revisions

| ID | User_ID | first_name | last_name | bio | country | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jon | Smith | A few words here. | Canada | Active |
| 2 | 1 | Jon | Smith | A few words here... | USA | Active |
| 3 | 1 | John | Smith | A few words here. Extra | USA | Active |
| 4 | 1 | John | Smith | A few words here. | USA | Active |
| 5 | 1 | John | Smith | A few words here. | UK | Active |
| 6 | 1 | John | Smit | A few words here. | USA | Pending |
| 7 | 1 | John | Smith | A few words here. | USA | Active |

I'm showing each time the last two entries of the tables and highlight the differences but I'm sure it could be done faster.

So for example I compare Users_revisions 7<->6 and show the differences (Last name + Status), on the next row 6<->5 (Last name + Country + Status), etc etc until you reach first entry and compare Users_revisions 1 with Users 1.

| IDs | first_name | last_name | bio | country | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7<->6 | - | Smith<->Smit | - | - | Active<->Pending |
| 6<->5 | - | Smit<->Smith | - | USA<->UK | Pending<->Active |

etc

Answer (score 0):

This is not very elegant but can help you in this problem!

```
<?php
// get the last two entries
$sql = ""; // define the query, remember to use prepared statements to improve security in your code!
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // perform the query
// need a while loop because we are handling multiple rows, instead you could use mysqli_fetch_all()
$rows = Array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
// now loop trough every column
$compared_rows = $rows[0]["ID"]."<->".$rows[1]["ID"]; // just the IDs of the compared rows
$comparison = Array();
for($i=2; $i<=6; $i++){ // Skip the ID columns
    $value = ($rows[0][$i] == $rows[1][$i]) ? "-" : $rows[0][$i]."<->".$rows[1][$i]; // if the values are same just return - , else return ValueA<->ValueB
    $comparison[$compared_rows][$i] = $value; // Put this column inside the final nested array, which can be easily handled
}

print_r($comparison); // Output the final array
?>
```